Eclipse Ditto - SSE and policies for specific features
I am playing with Eclipse Ditto. Now I'm learning about creating policies to hide private features for specific users.
With the HTTP API and the query to /api/2/things it works correctly when I define a policy to read only certain attributes.
However, when I use SSE (and modify the value of the features), I get no response about updates.
This is the policy entry:
    "test_sse": {
          "subjects": {
            "nginx:demo3": {
              "type": "generated"
            }
          },
          "resources": {
            "thing:/features/altitude": {
              "grant": [
                "READ"
              ],
              "revoke": []
            }
          },
          "importable": "implicit"
        }

On the other hand, if I modify the resource to "thing:/features/", I get the response for each modification via SSE (including all the features)
Is there any way to create policies for receiving updates (via SSE) only for specific features?
Thank you
